# Map netncf-file with different years and save the different layers in shapefiles

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2

Download from [this website](https://crudata.uea.ac.uk/cru/data/hrg/cru_ts_3.23/cruts.1506241137.v3.23/pet/) the following netncf-file: **cru_ts3.23.1991.2000.pet.dat.nc.gz**. This is a monthly raster with data from all over the world from january 1991 to december 2000

I am using ArcGis (multidimensional tool) to plot the map. However, **I don't manage to plot the maps per month.** I only receive one map, without time indication. I followed the instructions [here](http://disc.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/recipes/?q=recipes/How-to-Define-and-Visualize-Time-Dimension-in-ArcGIS) to build a time slider but the time slider doesn't work in the sense that it is showing time periods (1900 for instance) which is not in the data file I downloaded, and it doesn't slide.

A follow up question on this is that, once the time slider works, is it possible to save the different time layers seperately in different shapefiles such as in [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/188617/add-information-from-a-raster-nc-file-to-a-polygon-shapefile). I would like to use the separate shapefiles afterwards in R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following link provides an answer to this question! It appeared to be a settings problem!

https://geonet.esri.com/message/600953?et=watches.email.thread#comment-600953